# Sending Emoji or East Asian characters via POST

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

I'm trying to add Emoji and non-Latin character set support for my app. I have a MySQL database  with PHP as the bridge for communication back and forth. I've done a lot of research looking into the intricacies of getting Emoji, etc. to work with all of this, but I've encountered some strange problems.

If I send just one or two Emoji, everything goes fine. If I send a longer message, maybe 15 Emoji, something goes wrong and the data that the PHP script receives is somehow corrupted. I've also tried sending strings of 500 characters or so, in both Latin characters and Japanese characters, and they also arrive wrong. In one case, there were no errors, but some of my message got cut off. These errors all happen before the text even reaches the MySQL database, but testing it in a console, the database itself seems to handle all of these things just fine.

I've used the Chrome app Postman to try all of these problem-causing strings from a web browser directly, and they have all gone through with no problem

Some sample strings:

Works fine:

Gets cut off before the Emoji: I think it works? /???? ?? / / ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? 
*side note, it didn't work*

Corrupted string in the PHP script: 大地を踏みしめて 君は目覚めていく 天使の微笑みで 連れ出して! 孤独でも 一人じゃないさ 生まれてきたことに 必ず意味がある 優しさに 満ち溢れてる 青い地球(ほし)にありがとう

Corrupted string in the PHP script: "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt."

Again, all of these work fine when sent through Postman, so it seems to be a definite problem with my Swift code. The code in question:

```
func sendRequest(completion: (NSData?, NSURLResponse!, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let rString = NSString(string: requestString)
    let requestData = NSData(bytes: rString.UTF8String, length: rString.length)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    request.HTTPBody = requestData
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    
    func fullCompletion(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError?) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
        completion(data, response, error)
    }
    
    activeTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: fullCompletion)
    activeTask!.resume()
}
```

The code to assemble `requestString`:

```
func addVariable(name: String, value: String) {
    if !requestString.isEmpty {
        requestString += "&"
    }
    requestString += "\(name)=\(value)"
}
```

`session` is a `NSURLSession` object with the default configuration.

I think I've provided everything relevant but if I've forgotten something I'll happily add it.

Comment: You found that it works fine directly in web browsers, meaning you already isolated the issue to something in the iOS program...so tagging PHP is misdirection, since you've verified the PHP is fine.

Comment: As painful as it may seem, hex dump and actually examine the data.

Comment: That's a good point. Wasn't trying to deceive, fixed the tags

Answer (score 0):

What a strange solution it turned out to be. I was looking at the data directly thanks to Zaph's suggestion and found that it was getting cut short. Making the following change solved my issues:

```
//changed this:
let requestData = NSData(bytes: rString.UTF8String, length: rString.length)
//to this:
let requestData = rString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Comment: Swift correctly identifies unicode characters and a unicode  character may be comprised of more than one byte, in fact Emoji are generally from plane 1 and require several bytes, non-ASCII characters require at least two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to copy and paste the characters  and put it in a POST in Postman for example. If you are getting ? instead of emojis, it could be a problem where the text is stored with a different character set (charset), somewhere in a middle layer, such as the database. Make sure your database has the right charset and collation, such as in mysql it should be utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;